# Robovm : registering for push notification on IOS7 & IOS8

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, robovm

I am trying to register for push notifications on robovm.0.0.14 using my own simple binding PushManager as follows:

```
#import "PushManager.h"

@implementation PushManager

-(void) registerForPushNotifications
{

    NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications");
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Registering for IOS 8 and later");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

}

@end
```

It is working on IOS8 device but the application crashed on IOS 7 device on class linking phase as below:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/6C45E5E5-AF8F-43E8-9680-5CD3076DB1FF/Game.app/Game
>   Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit  in
>   /var/mobile/Applications/6C45E5E5-AF8F-43E8-9680-5CD3076DB1FF/Game.app/Game

I know `UIUserNotificationSettings` class is coming with iOS 8, but how can I ignore binding PushManager class on iOS 7 ?

Is there any workaround or fix for this iOS version specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

I check on the existence of the class `UIUserNotificationSettings`, which is related, and is only available for iOS 8.

```
NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings")
```

This is somewhat indirect, but works for me.